# How many dichlorinated products including stereoisomers can be isolated when (S)-2-chlorobutane reacts with Cl2 /hv?

Tags: organic-chemistry, stereochemistry, hydrocarbons

[image]

[image]
This is my attempt at solving this problem. I get 6 products. However my book says the answer is 5 products.

Comment: III and IV are the same. You can rotate III to make IV

Comment: I have to rotate the structure III in the plane of paper. How do you get IV from III by rotating it ? I don't get it. If I rotate III in the plane of paper 180 degrees, the structure remains the same, it doesn't change and it surely doesn't become IV.

Comment: Turn the paper over and look through it

Comment: Is rotation out of the plane of paper allowed in Fischer projections?

Comment: Are we assuming only one chlorination?

Comment: Actually, the 4th structure is wrong, you can't get that as C3 must have S configuration. But the structure you made has R configuration on both C2 and C3.

Answer (score 1):

Elaborating on what Waylander said, The C-2 carbon chlorine should be in S configuration so both (III) and (IV) structures can't be correct and only one with S configuration(IV) will be considered and rotating that will result in the other structure.